# Seeing issue with org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException

Tags: java, junit, spring-boot-test

Seeing an issue with spy and auto-wire along with Extend(SpringExtention)

> Argument should be a mock, but is: class
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtention.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestServer.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional
SampleServiceTest {
        
    @Spy
    @Autowire
    private TestRepo repo;
    @Mock
    SpecialTest test;
    @Mock
    SpecialTest1 test1;
    @InjectMock
    TestServiceTest testService;
        
    @InjectMock
    SampleServiceTest sampleServiceTest;
    
    @BeforeEach()
    void setup () {
        openMocks(this);
        when(testService.getId()).thenReturn(test);
        when(testService.getId()).thenReturn(test1);
    }
    
    @Test
    void test () {
    
    }
```

When I am using the spring-boot: 2.4.1 I am seeing the above issue.

Comment: make `TestRepo` as `mock` and write rule `when(repo.findById()).thenReturn(some mocked object)`

Comment: is there any way to test the using spy with a test  H2 database

Comment: what is the main purpose here, do you want to mock repository and test service layers or do integration with database and test service layer?

Comment: we need to do the integration with the database and test the service layer?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A unit test that tests your class in isolation or an integration test that includes the whole Spring context? If you goal is to write integration test that work with a Spring Test Context, rather use `@MockBean` to replace a bean inside your context. Please also refer to this [article](https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/) to understand the difference between `@Mock` and `@MockBean`.